# Angular Strap Tabs Justified

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-strap

I need to create 4 tabs in my app and after comparing Angular UI and Angular Strap, i decided to go with Angular Strap. I have lost hope in Angular Strap and this is my last try before i throw it out of my app.
I don't really get how a simple thing like making Tabs Justified is so difficult or am i missing something very basic?

Where and how should i include a class to make Tabs justified? Thanks

### Markup:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-offset-2" ng-controller="TabsAndTablesCtrl">
    <div ng-model="tabs.activeTab" tabs.navClass bs-tabs>
        <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" title="{{ tab.title }}" ng-bind="tab.content" bs-pane></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('tabsAndTablesModule', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);

app.controller('TabsAndTablesCtrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.tabs = [
            {title:'Projects', content: 'Raw denim you probably haven\'t heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica.'},
            {title:'Tasks', content: 'Food truck fixie locavore, accusamus mcsweeney\'s marfa nulla single-origin coffee squid. Exercitation +1 labore velit, blog sartorial PBR leggings next level wes anderson artisan four loko farm-to-table craft beer twee.'},
            {title:'Documents', content: 'Etsy mixtape wayfarers, ethical wes anderson tofu before they sold out mcsweeney\'s organic lomo retro fanny pack lo-fi farm-to-table readymade.'},
            {title:'Users', content: 'Etsy mixtape wayfarers, ethical wes anderson tofu before they sold out mcsweeney\'s organic lomo retro fanny pack lo-fi farm-to-table readymade.'}
        ];

        $scope.tabs.activeTab = 1;
});
```

Comment: How do you want it to be a justify? Reproduce your issue in fiddle

Comment: Sorry I cant make angular work on fiddle and i dont have enough reputation to add images to question.
Tabs are showing but i just need them to show with bootstrap class .nav-justified, which makes Tabs cover the parent div's width and not only float to left.

Comment: sorry for late reply, i needed normal tabs look not pills, its simply not working in angular strap and i have switched to angular ui bootstrap and that works perfectly.

Comment: You said you need justify tabs which is what below answer is for.

Comment: yes but it is showing as pills, i did try without "nav-pills" but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can add a class

```
<div ng-model="tabs.activeTab" nav-class='nav-justified nav-pills'..
```

See [Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/WpMB4buzacqOgKYoQzDf/)

And its also [documented](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/#tabs-usage)